# Unpredictable results on Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, loops, firefox, object

I have javascript object called `history`. While testing my application getting totally unpredictable results on chrome.

On firefox my application works well: when I `console.log(history)` getting following screen

[image]

But on chrome getting following

[image]

When I saw this screen for the first time, I thought maybe chrome adding some other details like length and state. But in fact, when I iterate through object (like below example) on chrome it prints out `state` first and value as null.

```
$.each(history, function (hash,files) { ...
```

And interesting part is, same code works on firefox like a charm.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't define a variable called `history`, because it is already part of the Web API interface,

> which provides an interface for manipulating the browser session
>   history (pages visited in the tab or frame that the current page is
>   loaded in) - [Window.history (Web API Interfaces | MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.history)

It is contained under the `window` object, so it is a global variable in the webpage. You can't overwrite it, but it depends on the browser which one will precede the other.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use the variable history change it to something else since [window.history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.history) clashes.

Comment: is that related with name?

Comment: I changed. Same issue exists